# Macro not recording color change of series in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to record a macro where I'll change the Marker color, line color,  marker fill. But all I got in recording is

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using excel 2007

Comment: The macro recorder is a black box. As you have discovered, it doesn't reliably record everything. There is nothing to do about the macro recorder itself. It *does* tell you that you need to use `SeriesCollection` to make the changes that you want. Explore that part of the Excel Object Model. It *is* possible to change marker color, etc. programmatically.

Comment: @Pramod try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to define the new Series with a variable, and set different parameters related to it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim Cht_Series                          As Series

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

Set Cht_Series = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)

With Cht_Series
    ' line weight
    .Format.Line.Weight = 1

    ' Edit #1
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue

    ' Line color red
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)

    ' marker style
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond

    ' marker size
    .MarkerSize = 8

    ' marker Fill color
    .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 176, 80) ' Marker Fill color Green

    ' marker foreground color
    .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' marker foreground Black (lines around)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. But the line color is not changing. Marker color and marker fill are working as expected. And I want to rgb color to the line. I have something specific. Is it possible? I'm not sure why line color is not applied

Comment: Even that's not working. But when I used Format.Fill.Forecolor, it is changing the marker fill. But Format.Line.Forecolor is not working

Comment: Any idea why it's not working? I referred internet and everyone suggest same format. I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: @Pramod `.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)` is not changing the line color to green ?

Comment: Nope. It's not changing. I tried changing the rgb formats. But still none are applied.

Comment: @Pramod all the other parameters are working and changing ?

Comment: @Pramod try edited code for line color options (there are more)

Comment: I also test this code in Excel 2010 and do not observe the line changes colors. I've seen this before, and there is a workaround/solution, I will try to remember what it is...

Comment: Please post the answer if you find something @david

Comment: I agree, but still Pramod says none of the colors are changing anything. What type of chart are you using ? is it some type of a line chart ?

Comment: @Pramod what type of chart are you trying this on ?

Comment: @DavidZemens is `.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192,0,0)` not changing your chart (line type) to red ?

Comment: @ShaiRado This is a known bug in Excel 2007/2010. What version are you using?

Comment: OK, the .RGB assignment is working in 2010. But the `ObjectThemeColor` is not

Comment: @DavidZemens 2010 , working very nicely on a line type chart, and it's running on 10-20 other PCs that running my code for chart format

Comment: Man... this is crazy..  the solution John pointed is actually working. I can't believe this

Comment: @Pramod and everyone, this is funny, I have it in my full code - didn't remember why I had it at the time :) , added that to my edited code

Comment: Lol.. seriously.. why is it working if we make it invisible and visible

Comment: @ I don't remember, but I'm using a similar code for the past 2 months

Comment: Ehhhhh it **is** working for me as @ShaiRado has done. Actually, mine is working even without setting `.Visible` to false/true. I think I was trying to look at too many things earlier, and was not noticing some changes...